# Why is VS Code opening directory instead of .html file?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Whenever I run any html file in VS, the live server view opens the directory instead of the html file. I have tried all the solutions from similar questions on here and havent been able to find a solution. I have tried closing the workspace and adding it into a workspace again and opening it directly with liveserver and it still opens the listing directory. I have also tried renaming the html file to index.html and still no success. Anyone know what Im missing? Cant seem to find a solution it was working an hour ago not sure what I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check your launch.json file. Check if you have the following lines:

```
"url": "http://localhost:5500/",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the live-server plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you to everyone who tried to help. After trying all solutions I could find:reinstalling,changing workspace,changing name to index.html,and checking the launch.json file. I ended up fixing this problem by rebooting Xubuntu. (Oracle VM VirtualBox).